# xml node parent ID c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to copy some xml node from a template to place them in another xml. The structure of the xml follows.

```
<grandparent>
    <parent>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
    </parent>
    <parent>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
        <children>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
            <grandchildren/>
        </children>
    </parent>
</grandparent>
```

Is it possible for me to tranverse down the second parent and the selected children and grab all the grandchildren?And insert all the grandchildren into another xml file?

Comment: Where does parent ID come into it?

Comment: The answer is yes, but you need to provide sample code how you are dealing with XML so someone may provide more detailed answer.

Comment: @Rawling,interesting question... it looks like folks just type random text into titles today...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
        string input = @"<grandparent>
            <parent>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren/>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren/>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren/>
                </children>
            </parent>
            <parent>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren id=""1""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""2""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""3""/>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren id=""4""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""5""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""6""/>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <grandchildren id=""7""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""8""/>
                    <grandchildren id=""9""/>
                </children>
            </parent>
        </grandparent>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
        // Use XDocument.Load method to load XML content from file
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(<filepath>);

        IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc
            .Root
            .Elements("parent")
            .ElementAt(1)
            .Descendants("grandchildren");

        XElement rootElement = new XElement("rootElement");
        rootElement.Add(elements);

        rootElement.Save(@"C:\Doc2.xml");
```

I presume that the XML you posted is not just a fragment but rather entire XML content you wish to parse.
The tricky part here is that you are accessing element by it's ordinal number, it should be done by some kind of ID attribute on `parent` element, so it could be accessed by comparing it's ID instead of using `ElementAt` method that retrieves the element according to it's ordinal position.
I added the `id` attribute to `grandchildren` so it would be visible that the `grandchildren` elements belong to the second `parent` element, not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 XElement doc = XElement.Load("c:\\yourXML.xml");
 XElement newdoc = new XElement("GrandChildren");
 foreach (XElement x in doc.Descendants("parent").Skip(1).Descendants("children").Descendants("grandchildren"))
 {
       newdoc.Add(x);
 }
```

newDoc now contains your required XML..